# std::cin is not accepting input

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the first program working from "Accelerated C++".

I was having trouble getting the program to stay open without shutting down, so I decided to put a `int i = 0;` and `cin >> i;` after `main()` returns. Unfortuantely, it doesn't seem to take any input, no matter where I put that `cin` statement.

If it helps, it is using an `istream` reference to accept `cin` input. I can't  figure out how to enter code on this site.

Comment: _"I can't figure out how to enter code on this site"_ : You can paste them directly as text then use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to display them as code.

Comment: I pasted in my code and then pressed ctrl+k before each line and all it did was send my code to the next line after writing "enter text here." I have no idea what it wants me to do.

Comment: Try highlighting the entire code then clicking instead the `{ }` button.

Comment: `I decided to put ... after main() returns` If you put something after the return statement, it definitely won't happen.

Answer (score 1):

For most of my adult life, I used [`system("PAUSE")`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) without any problems to keep the program window open. It's not good for real-time systems, of course, but it's simple and powerful because you're actually running a console command and it can be used to make console scripts.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

inline void Pause () { cout << "\n"; system ("PAUSE); }

int main () { Pause (); }
```

This solution is not 100% portable, but it will work on PCs.  A more portable solution is:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdio>

void Pause() {
  cout << "\nPress any key to continue...";
  while (_getch() < 0)
    ;
}
```

`cin` is good for doing simple things, but what I do is wrap the std library in C functions and use those because it can dramatically improve compile times to hide the std library headers in the implementation files.

The prefered method in C++ is `std::getline()` using `std::string`, though many teachers won't let you use that.

With `cin`, you also have to clear input errors and use `ignore()` to throw away a specific number of chars.

```
#include <string>

string foo;
cout << "Why do they always use foo? ";
getline (cin, foo);
cout << "You just entered" << foo;

int bar;
cout << "\nThe answer is because programmers like to go to the bar."
        "\nHow many times have you seen foo bar in an example? ";
while (!(cin >> bar)) {
  cout << "\nPlease enter a valid number: ";
  cin.clear ();
  cin.ignore (10000, '\n');
}
```

My many years of experience have taught me to put the `\n` char at the beginning of output lines as opposed to the end of them.

Comment: You can also wrap whatever call you are using to keep the terminal window open on windows with `#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64) ... your call to keep terminal open ... #endif`. The makes the code a bit more portable without it waiting when it shouldn't be when compiled elsewhere.

Comment: "*I've also had some problems with cin skipping*" - then you haven't learned how to use it correctly/effectively. `_getch()` (and `conio.h` in general) is even less portable than `system("pause")`. Use `cin.get()` instead. And you should use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` when calling `ignore()` to ignore the remainder of a line.

Comment: Cale and Remy. Thank you so much. cin.ignore (1000, '\n'); fixes it. But why?

Comment: I think it's already set for the first time by default initialization, but don't quote me. You're just trying to reset it.